# Broken "Edit email settings" link on the footer of Stack Overflow emails

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, broken-link

At footer of emails that I receive from Stack Overflow, there is a "*Edit email settings*" link that suppose to take me to edit email settings page. But it results in a custom 404 page.
[image]

URL of link:
https://email.stackoverflow.com/subscriptions/manage?id=XXX&auth=XXX

Comment: Hmm... How old was the email this link was found in?

Comment: less than 24 hours old

Comment: What is the final URL?

Comment: @MikeEzzati you should never share that URL, it's HMAC auth-ed, anyone with that link can edit your email subscriptions (even when not logged in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deeply apologize that your question went so long without an answer.

Looks like the email in question was the weekly Stack Overflow Newsletter.

I just confirmed with one of our engineers that there had been a bug with that link, and that it was patched yesterday.

Sorry for the inconvenience. That link should work from now on in future emails.

BTW, you can always visit the [Email Settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) to view or change your email preferences.