# "Edit Email Settings" link in emails leads to a 404 error if I am not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, 404-not-found, unsubscribe

In the "1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox" email, there is an "Edit email settings" link at the bottom. If I am not logged in to stack exchange, this goes to a "Page not found" page.

I found [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308721/broken-edit-email-settings-link-on-the-footer-of-stack-overflow-emails), but the answer there says this was fixed in May but I just clicked on the link in an email I received today and still got the "Page not found" page.

Usually, to comply with CAN-SPAM, unsubscribe links don't require a login. If a login is required, you should at least prompt me to log in rather than giving an error page.

Here is a screenshot of the email I am referring to. I'll note that there is no "unsubscribe" link, only an "email settings" link.

[image: screenshot of email]

Comment: This has been an issue for a while - the current intentional behavior is to throw a 404 for the email settings link if you are not logged in. I've long wanted it to show a login page instead because a 404 is very confusing. But to be clear: you do not need to be logged in for the unsubscribe link to work. You only need to be logged in to make additional changes to your email settings.

Comment: @animuson I've updated the question with a screenshot. There is no "unsubscribe" link. Only "Edit email settings".

Comment: Huh, I wonder why that email type doesn't have one. There's normally another link before that one titled "Unsubscribe from emails like this".

Comment: We have found a regression here - thanks for the report! Samo is working on a fix now.

Comment: Hey @Nick is Samo still working on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed a while ago; apologies for not updating this post sooner.

Thanks for the report, and please let us know if you're still running into issues with the "edit settings" link.